# Windows mobile C# Validate a username and password against Active Directory?

Tags: c#, active-directory, windows-mobile

i try to validate the username und password against Active Director from a Windows Mobile devive. On XP I use this:

```
    using System.Security;
    using System.DirectoryServices;
    using System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory;
    ...
    DirectoryEntry entry = new DirectoryEntry(srvr, usr, pwd);
            object nativeObject = entry.NativeObject;
    ...
```

but these are not available in Windows Mobile.

Is there a way to do this in Windows Mobile?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The .NET Compact Framework doesn't support LDAP (therefore Active Directory Authentication).

You can use P/invoke to call the native methods from .Net though. An example on how to do it via C++ is provided in the link below.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa912620.aspx

Comment: It appears the OP has posted some very close code, but he has a **CallingConvention** of `Cdecl`, and all I can see available under Windows Mobile is `Winapi`. How would I get around this?

Comment: No, I did not. Thanks (forgot to give you the +1 before, but it's there now). However, I can't seem to get the calling convention to work as set forth in the OP's answer (see my comments there).